# errror : getline(cin,name) undeclared use of "cin"

Tags: c++

i have this program

```
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int name;
    getline(cin,name);
    return 0;
}
```

when i compile,this is what i get
"C:\Users\user\Documents\dev c++\getline.cpp `cin' undeclared (first use this function)"
what is the problem?

Comment: need to `#include <iostream>`

Comment: You need to include `<iostream>`

Comment: This close reason is not good for this question. But sadly, it's the best one from all available.

Comment: (Imagine me being a paper clip) It seems you're trying to read a name, but `int` cannot hold a name. Did you want to use `std::string name;` instead?

Comment: @Zeta you must truly be a totally imaginary one (whose name should never be mentioned) since you sound intelligent, offer helpful advise, grasp the context and didn't make run out of the room screaming ;)

Answer (score 2):

Guess what?? You need `std::string` as well.. :D

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string name;
    getline(cin,name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i have included iostream and it is not working,also what is std::string and D? i am new to programming.

Comment: @geek2 are you using exactly same code as in this answer? and when you say not working.. then what exactly not working? any error?

Comment: reality,thank you,it worked out but i still have a problem about which other built-in function can i use to replace cout just like getline replaces cin and how would i use it? thanks

Comment: @geek2: `getline` doesn't replace `cin`. If you want to print the name, just use `std::cout << "Well, hello there, " << name << "!" << std::endl;`. That being said, get a book, don't learn from snippets of the internet.

Answer (score 2):

When you encounter such an error, the solution is invariably that you need to include a header. Here's how to work out which one you need:

1. Go to http://en.cppreference.com/
2. Search for [`cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?search=cin).
3. Follow the [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) that is returned.
4. Read the text at the top which details where the object is defined. In this case it says: *Defined in header `<iostream>`*.
5. Add `#include <iostream>` to your code.

Answer (score 1):

`std::cin` is not part of the language, but is actually provided by libraries. As others have said, you need to `#include <iostream>`, which, like `<string>` is a library that provides various pieces of functionality. You'll also get `std::cout` for putting information back out, when you choose to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the C++ language is that some parts are "library features" which means, whilst they are provided for you, they obey the rules of the language and you have to include their header files.

If you had actually put `std::cin` in your code you might have got an error message telling you that `cin` is not part of namespace `std` which of course it is but you have to `#include` the appropriate header.